# Como converter um txt para csv em perl?

Tags: regex, csv, txt, perl

Olá, Rapazeada.

Eu sou novo na linguagem perl. Estou precisando converter um arquivo txt para csv.

Segue o codigo que consegui fazer até agora.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my $filename = "interfaces.txt";

open(fh, $filename) or die "não abriu";
@fh = <fh>;
close fh;

print "Interfaces;Status;Protocol;Description\n";

foreach my $linha (@fh){
        if($linha =~ /[gi]+\d\W\d+|[te]+\d\W\d+/gi){
                my @te = $linha;

                foreach my $linha2 (@te){
                        $linha2 =~ s/\s\ //g;
                        print "$linha2";
                }
        }
}
```

Esse é o conteudo do txt:

```
Interface                      Status         Protocol Description
Gi1/1                          up             up       descrição...
Gi1/2                          up             down     descrição...
Gi1/3                          up             up       descrição...
Gi1/48                         admin down     down     descrição...
Te1/49                         up             up       descrição...
Te1/50                         up             up       descrição...
```

Assim ele deveria ficar:

```
Interface;Status;Protocol;Description
Gi1/1;up;up;descrição...
Gi1/2;up;down;descrição...
Gi1/3;up;up;descrição...
Gi1/48;admin down;down;descrição...
Te1/49;up;up;descrição...
Te1/50;up;up;descrição...
```

E isso é oq eu consegui até agora:

```
Interface;Status;Protocol;Description
Gi1/1up up descrição...
Gi1/2up down descrição...
Gi1/3up up descrição...
Gi1/48 admin down down descrição...
Te1/49 up up descrição...
Te1/50 up up descrição...
```

Quem puder ajudar, ficarei agradecido.

Comment: Dê uma olhada na chamada `split`. Também não recomendaria ter os cabeçalhos fixos dentro do seu programa - o tratamento para a linha de cabeçalhos pode ser o mesmo que para todo o arquivo texto, e o seu programa fica genérico. dessa forma ele funcionará apenas para _este_ arquivo específico.

Comment: Sobre os conceitos envolvidos -tenha em mente que um arquivo "csv" _também_ é um arquivo texto, só que estruturado de acordo com algumas convenções. A extensão no caso é só um lembrete para o usuário. No caso, o seu arquivo ".txt"  pode ser entendido diretamente como um CSV por varias aplicações, bastando indicar que o separador são espaços em branco, e não o ";".

Comment: @jsbueno, no caso do cabeçalho, ele vai generico mesmo, só o conteudo q ir mudar. Eu preciso converter para csv para diminuir os espaços em branco e colocar " ; " para separa, pois já tentei com os espaços em branco, porem ele interpreta  "admin down down" com 3 valores, no caso são 2 "admin down;down". Estou vendo como esse fuciona a função split já tive uma boa progreção.

Comment: hmm..isso do admin down down pode ser problema - consegue ver se são espaços ou tabs (caratcrer de código 9) separando as colunas?

Comment: No caso, são espeços q estão separando as colunas. Tentei converter para \t mas não tive sucesso.

Comment: @jsbueno, consegui concluir o scritp. Muito obrigado pela ajuda. Vou colar a resolução como resposta.

Comment: Ola @Natanael, Não altere o titulo da pergunta para indicar que seu problema foi resolvido. Se você achou uma resposta diferente das propostas pela comunidade considere responder sua própria pergunta, mas tarde você poderá aceitar ela, isso pode ajudar a pessoas com o mesmo problema =D -- [Posso responder minha própria pergunta?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) -- Se alguma reposta da comunidade te ajudou considere aceitar, essa seria a melhor forma de agradecer. =D -- [Tour]

Comment: Ah, sim. Muito obrigado pela atenção @IcaroMartins

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Já agora uma alternativa um pouco mais trotskista:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
while(<>){                                ## para cada linha
  s/(\s{2,}|\t| (?=[A-Z]))/;/g;           ## substuir espaços por ;
  print                                   ## imprimi-la
}
```

Onde se está apenas a substituir (`s/(\s{2,}|\t| (?=[A-Z]))/;/g`)

- 2 ou mais espaços, ou
- um tab ou
- um único espaço se seguido de uma letra maiúscula

por o separador `;`

Podes ainda fazê-lo directamente na linha de comando:

```
perl -pE 's/(\s{2,}|\t| (?=[A-Z]))/;/g' input > output.csv
```

Comment: Sua solução é muito mais simples comparado a minha. Valeu por ter compartilhado, funcionou perfeitamente!

Answer (score 3):

O problema foi resolvido!!

Segue script solução:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my $filename = "interfaces.txt";
my $interface;
my $status;
my $protocol;
my $description;

open(fh, $filename) or die "não abriu";
@fh = <fh>;
close fh;

print "Interfaces;Status;Protocol;Description\n";

foreach my $linha (@fh){
        if($linha =~ /[gi]+\d\W\d+|[te]+\d\W\d+/gi){
                $linha =~ s/\s  //g;
                my @te = split / /, $linha;
                $interface = $te[0];

                $linha =~ s/Gi+\d\W\d+\s+|Te+\d\W\d+\s+//g;
                my @tt = split / /, $linha;

                if($tt[0] =~ /up|down/gi){
                        $status = $tt[0];
                         if($tt[1] =~ /up|down/g){
                                $protocol = $tt[1];
                        } else{
                                $protocol = $tt[2];
                        }
                } elsif($tt[0] =~ /admin/gi) {
                        $status = "$tt[0] $tt[1]";
                        $protocol = $tt[3];
                }

                $linha =~ s/\s  |Gi+\d\W\d+|Te+\d\W\d+|up|admin|down//g;
                $linha =~ s/^\s+//gm;
                $description = $linha;

                print "$interface;$status;$protocol;$description";
        }
}
```